# Windows Server 2016 Windows Update - specify the time of install

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2016

I've setup several servers with Windows Server 2016 and I've some questions regarding Windows Update.

I've a WSUS server deployed with a GPO for all my servers but I configure different options on each server regarding reboot time and automatic install.

I would like to perfom the same with Windows Server 2016 but I can't find any option to select the install time like with Windows Server 2012 R2. For instance, I've two ADFS servers in a farm. I would like to install updates on the first at 3AM and at 5AM for the second.

I know I can achieve that with a GPO but every server is different. My GPO only configure the WSUS URL. My only option is to use the Local Group Policies on each server.

Does someone has a better way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: unless I'm missing something here, you just need additional GPOs with the different configuration options

Answer (score 0):

In WSUS create different computer groups with different deadline times and move the servers into those groups. For me I have the updates for the WSUS server itself deadline at 11PM.  Then I have general servers deadline at either 1AM or 3AM and then Hyper-V hosts deadline at 4AM.  WSUS group names have to be unique, so the group tree is not like a directory tree.